# I want to find the count of current element within its parent element using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<a>
  <z/>
  <b/>
  <b/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</a>
```

I want to find the count of 'b' within 'a' when my parsing current node is 'c' using XSLT.
Is it possible to do this using XSLT?
I am not aware of what the element name 'b' would be, i.e. for its preceding sibling.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your title says you want "*the count of the current element within its parent element*". If you are in the context of `c`, then this would mean the count of all siblings named `c` . But then you say you want to count `b` - but you don't know the name of `b`. How then do you propose to identify `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are positioned on `c` tag, or whatever the element is actually called, then to get the count of the preceding siblings, you would do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)" />
```

EDIT: In answer to your comment, if you don't want to count all siblings, but only the count of the immediately preceding one, and the ones with the same name before that, you could try this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current()/preceding-sibling::*[1])])" />
```

This would not work though in the case you had multiple `c` nodes under one parent...

```
<a>
  <z/>
  <b/>
  <b/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <z/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</a>
```

In this case, you could define a key like this, to group elements by the unique id of the first following element with a different name:

```
<xsl:key name="keyc" match="*" use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())][1])" />
```

Then you can get the count like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('keyc', generate-id()))" />
```

Here are the three options in action....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="keyc" match="*" use="generate-id(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="c">
      <c>
         <example1>
             <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)" />
          </example1>
         <example2>
             <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current()/preceding-sibling::*[1])])" />
          </example2>
          <example3>
             <xsl:value-of select="count(key('keyc', generate-id()))" />
          </example3>
      </c>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it gets all count i want only for 'b'

Comment: In your question you say you are `not aware of the element name 'b'`, so you can't really count something if you don't know what it is. Are you actually saying you want to get the immediately preceding sibling of `c`, and count the number of occurrences of that?

Comment: I've amended my answer showing a number of different options you could try.

Comment: thank you lots of options the first one solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xsl:number`. It prints out the numer of the current element, formatted as required.

There are various options concerning how to perform the numeration,
e.g. multi-level or alphabetic one.

Actually it is quite a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the count of 'b' within 'a' when my parsing current node is 'c'

Let me rephrase that:
you want to count all occurrences of `<b>` which are on the same level as `<c>`.

This XSLT does the job by calling an `<xsl:template>` with a parameter:
the `local-name` of the element to be counted (in this case 'b'):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output  omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="//c">                           <!-- select the desired target element -->
   <xsl:call-template name="count">
     <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="'b'" />  <!-- name of the element -->
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="count">                         <!-- count all matching elements before and after -->
   <xsl:param name="elemName" />
   <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = $elemName]) + count(following-sibling::*[local-name() = $elemName])" />
 </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the case of your example the output simply is:

> 3